# Attempting to Read parcquet files on linked storage in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I am attempting to give access to parquet files on a Gen2 Data Lake container.  I have owner RBAC on the container but would prefer to limit access in the container for other users.

My Query is very simple:

```sql
SELECT
  TOP 100 *
FROM
  OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://aztsworddataaipocacldl.dfs.core.windows.net/pocacl/Top/Sub/part-00006-c62926ba-c530-4ad8-87d1-cf38c67a2da3-c000.snappy.parquet',
    FORMAT='PARQUET'
  ) AS [result]
```

When I run this I have no problems connecting.  I have attempted to add ACL rights onto the files (and of course the containing folders 'Top' and 'Sub').

[I've give RWX on the 'Top' folder using Storage Explorer and default so that it cascades to the 'Sub' folder and parquet files as I add them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkssn.png)

When my colleague attempts to run the SQL script the get the error message. `Failed to execute query. Error: File 'https://aztsworddataaipocacldl.dfs.core.windows.net/pocacl/Top/Sub/part-00006-c62926ba-c530-4ad8-87d1-cf38c67a2da3-c000.snappy.parquet' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.`
****NB similar results are also experienced in Spark but with a 403 instead****

SQL on-demand provides a link to the  [following help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand#query-fails-because-file-cannot-be-opened) after the error, it suggests:

> If your query fails with the error saying 'File cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process' and you're sure both file exist and it's not used by another process it means SQL on-demand can't access the file. ***This problem usually happens because your Azure Active Directory identity doesn't have rights to access the file. By default, SQL on-demand is trying to access the file using your Azure Active Directory identity. To resolve this issue, you need to have proper rights to access the file.*** Easiest way is to grant yourself 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the storage account you're trying to query.

I don't wish to grant Storage Blob Data Contributor or Storage Blob Data Reader as this gives access to every file on the container and not just those I want end users to be able to query.  We have found the same experience occurs for SSMS connecting to parquet external tables.

So then in parts:

1. Is this the correct pattern using ACL to grant access, or should I use another method?
2. Are there settings on the Storage Account or within my query/notebook that I should be enabling to support ACL?*
3. Has ACL been implemented on Synapse Workspace to date given that we're still in preview?

*I have resisted pasting my entire settings as I really have no idea what is relevant and what entirely irrelevant to this issue but of course can supply.

Comment: When you did the `CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL` and `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE` what details did you use?  Did you use a SAS key for example?  As I understand it, SQL on demand only offers AAD or SAS key access.

Comment: 2 points on that 1 I have not in our internal environment used the create Database nor Create External Data Source at this time however on another environment I have.  I did not use a SAS key.  I was under the impression that Access Control Lists uses AAD, is this not correct?

Comment: As an update:
The Access Control documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#access-control-lists-on-files-and-directories) stipulates that :
>If you assigned a role to a security principal at the storage account-level, you can use access control lists to grant that security principal elevated access to specific files and directories.
Which role (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor) best allows me to set and ACL **NB** I have tried this with contributer.

Comment: I am suggesting use SAS for fine-grain control - have a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=shared-access-signature#supported-storage-authorization-types). I can do an example if you need, but it's all there.

Comment: @wBob thanks, I'll look at that, will this work for querying spark sql from sql on-demand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that the ACL feature was not working correctly in Preview for Azure Synapse Analytics.

I have now managed to get it to work. At present I see that once Read|Execute is provided to a folder it allows access to the files contained within that folder and sub folders.  Access is available even when no specific ACL access is provided on a file in a sub folder.  This is not quite what I expected however it provides enough for me to proceed: only giving access to the Gold folder allows for separation of access to the files I want to let users query and the working files that I want to keep hidden.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign ACL to a folder it's not propagated recursively to all files inside the folder. Only new files inherit from the folder.

You can see this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#permissions-inheritance)

Comment: Hi Jovan.  I added the ACL to the Top folder before adding the sub folder and the files to account for this.  As you stated only new files inherit from the folder.  I think I stated that in the OP? Perhaps you missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to azure storage explorer change ACL permissions in the route Folder and right click on your storage and click on "propogate access control lists"